# Story Identification: Graphic Novel about the Baker Street Irregulars fighting a supernatural threat

Tags: story-identification

Read at a library circa 2008. Plot centered on the Baker Street Irregulars investigating a supernatural threat. Moriarty showed up at some point, talking about the golden ratio and its place in alchemy. I believe the plot involved something about time going haywire and different beings from different epochs showing up in London. The only distinctive image I can remember is a scene set in a graveyard of hundreds of giant humanoids with elongated skulls. No idea of author or publisher.

Comment: League of Extraordinary Gentlemen maybe?

Comment: This could be a translation of the French comic *Les Quatre de Baker Street* (The Baker Street Quartet) by  Jean-Blaise Djian, Olivier Legrand, and David Etien. I have read the first volume in Danish translation. I can't however, recall any supernatural elements.. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Quatre_de_Baker_Street

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be [THE IRREGULARS](https://www.darkhorse.com/Books/12-777/The-Irregulars-TPB) from Dark Horse?
[image]

- Published 2005
- Supernatural (Lovecraftian) element
- Moriaty appears

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Could you [edit] in any details to your answer of why this story matches the OP's description? Thanks.

Comment: This was it!!!! I remember that face! Thankyou so much!